# Error binding a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to consume a Web API that gives the list of **Dealers** and trying to bind it into a `DropdownList` in mvc. However, I'm facing an error:

> Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'DealerName'.

The service I'm consuming is returning the list of Dealer details and I've to display that into a web grid in mvc with two dropdown lists of **Dealer Name** and **Statement Month** for search criteria. SO, I have created a ViewModel to accumulate the result from service with two addtional properties to be used to bind in the dropdownlist. Following is the code:

**Web Service Result** - An IEnumerable List of this class:

```
public class DealerReportResponse
{
    public string DealerCode { get; set; }
    public string DealerName { get; set; }
    public string StatementReceivedOnDate { get; set; }
    public int StatementReceivedOnDay { get; set; }
    public string StatementReceivedOnMonth { get; set; }
}
```

#### My View Model is:

```
public class DealerReportViewModel
{
    public List<string> DealerName { get; set; }
    public List<string> DealerStatementMonth { get; set; }
    public List<DealerReportResponse> DealerReportDetails { get; set; }
}
```

#### Here is the Controller where I'm passing the model to the View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      try
      {
          DealerReportViewModel model = new DealerReportViewModel();
          var serviceHost = //url;
          var service = new JsonServiceClient(serviceHost);
          var response = service.Get<IEnumerable<DealerReportResponse>>(new DealerReportRequest());
          if (response != null)
          {
               model.DealerName = response.Select(x => x.DealerName).Distinct().ToList();
               model.DealerStatementMonth = response.Select(x => x.StatementReceivedOnMonth).Distinct().ToList();
               model.DealerReportDetails = response.ToList();
               return View("DealerReportGrid", model);
           }
           else
           {
               //do something
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            //catch exception
       }
 }
```

#### And In the View, I'm trying to bind the model into a dropdown list as follows:

```
<!-- Search Box -->
@model DealerFinancials.UI.Models.DealerReport.DealerReportViewModel
<div id="searchBox">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DealerName, 
         new SelectList(Model.DealerName, "DealerName", "DealerName"),
         "All Categories", 
         new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Category" })
</div>
```

However, I'm not able to bind the DealerName list to a dropdown list. I'm not sure about the error. Please help if I'm missing something to pass along with my model to the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error generating SelectList: You need to generate it from `Model.DealerReportDetails` and not from `Model.DealerName` . So instead of `new SelectList(Model.DealerName, "DealerName", "DealerName")` use 
`new SelectList(Model.DealerReportDetails , "DealerName", "DealerName")`

```
@model DealerFinancials.UI.Models.DealerReport.DealerReportViewModel
<div id="searchBox">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DealerName, 
         new SelectList(Model.DealerReportDetails , "DealerName", "DealerName"),
         "All Categories", 
         new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Category" })
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried the code but it is throwing this error:
 
CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable, object, System.Collections.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: See the updated version. You need to use `Model.DealerReportDetails` as a data-source for select list

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the help Alex. Been struck with issue from last 1 hour. Big thanks :)